# How to know debug/profile hanged C# application in the given situation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have mulch-threaded program (console application) written in C#

It runs fine up to 6 -10 hours later it fails and stops , console does not closes and shows the last successful log

Error logs (all possible) it writes in a file.

if even IO exception occurs it writes it in Windows Event

There are Memory Guard and Thread Guards too that limit program to given limit.

When it stops (6-10 hours later) nothing happens no error log, heart beat, database calls, memory usage, I can see the thread is spawn around 70% maximum limit set.

I know it might be a memory leak because of that threads might not be getting free due to database call latencies.

I just wanted to work on this stopped application to know the exact problem, like where is the memory leak or which call does blockage.

Are there any tools available that works on this hanged/stopped application? What should be proper way to proceed.

I used ANTS memory pro-filer, performance pro-filers but all these tools work on running applications.

What most i am can get is a Memory Dump.

Suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:
Initially I don't want to rerun it wait hours to debug, if there is no way that would be the last option.

I tried to attach debugger and put breakpoints, it says "The breakpoint will not currently hit...."

Comment: Can you run the application within Visual Studio and in debug mode?

Comment: Probably, you can work on memory dump to figure out thread executed while application is running. In multiple thread applications, there is small code block that would effect the whole system.

Comment: is it a WPF app or a win form app? If its WPF, watch for the events you use along with the threads, and try to use weak events instead of the normal events that create strong references and do not free up automatically in most cases. If its a winform app, the best is to look closely to the code that creates the thread and possibly use background worker thread for efficient usage. In my opinion, you will have to find the error before your app hangs, as the tools also wont be able to report much after app stops responding.

Comment: please revisit question EDIT: section

Comment: This sounds like deadlock, a classic threading problem.  Pretty hard to debug if this doesn't happen often and you cannot reproduce it on your dev machine.  You do need to get to a point where you can attach a debugger or open the minidump to see what's going on.  The most typical resolution for threading bugs in a program is a drastic rewrite.

Comment: When attaching the VS debugger, have you deployed the .pdb files with the .exe?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Debug Diagnostics Tool v1.2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580960) It does exactly what you need and has a easily understandable wizard for different problems.

If you don't want to use this tool, i would attach a debugger to the hanging process, you should be able to see at least which threads are still running and in which module

Answer (score 0):

First you should have a look in the event Viewer.
Then if your application crashes without logs, it could be due to an unhandled Exception.
Put the following code in the main method :

```
Application.ThreadException += (sender, arg) => { log.Error("Unhandled exception : "+e.Exception);};
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

Good luck